# Is it possible to use AspNet Api Versioning with Net 6 Minimal APIs?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, aspnet-api-versioning, minimal-apis

I am using Net 6 Minimal APIs:

```
application.MapGet("countries", async (IService service) => {
  var countries = await mediator.Send(request);
  return Results.Ok(countries);
});
```

Is it possible to use AspNet Api Versioning with Net 6 Minimal APIs? How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<s>ASP.NET API Versioning with *Minimal APIs* is **not** currently supported. It is on the roadmap as a feature enhancement.</s>

ASP.NET API Versioning now supports *Minimal APIs*.

New Packages:

- [Asp.Versioning.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.Http) - *Minimal APIs*
- [Asp.Versioning.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.Http) - MVC Core
- [Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.Http) - API Explorer Extensions

Examples:

- [Minimal API Example](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/93bd8dc7582ec14c8ec97997c01cfe297b085e17/examples/AspNetCore/WebApi/MinimalApiExample)
- [Minimal OpenAPI Example](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/93bd8dc7582ec14c8ec97997c01cfe297b085e17/examples/AspNetCore/WebApi/MinimalOpenApiExample)

Comment: Yes, we should get this working for .NET 7 :) (related https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36007)

Comment: Could you take a look into this one please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454634/get-key-from-uri-in-createref-net-core-6-odata

Comment: @soccer7 the question is not related to API Versioning, but I answered it anyway.